# Change order of topics in r package manual

Tags: r, r-package

My R package contains two functions and two example datasets. Sorted alphabetically the file names of the datasets (e.g., ex_dataset_1.rda, ex_dataset_2.rda) are before the file names of the R functions (e.g., function_1.R, function_2.R). Therefore, in the manual of the package,there is

1. the documentation of the package
2. the documention of the example datasets
3. the documentation of the R functions

I want to change the order of 2. and 3. because the implementation of the R functions is the relevant content of the package and the example datasets are just nice-to-have for testing the functions. Is it possible to change the order in the manual? I tried using the collate field in the DESCRIPTION file but this did not work, neither .rda nor .Rd files are allowed in the collate field.

Comment: Not that I know of but maybe a vignette is the way to go.  It explains usage in a fine controlled way ...more of a how than what is in the package.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped to avoid the vignette effort but ok, I will start to read...